# mysql large table with geo-locations - find intersections

Tags: mysql, sql, gps, geolocation

I have a large table ( > 20 millions rows ) with this structure

```
[ Id, IdUser (int), Latitude(double), Longitude (double), EventDateTime (datetime) ]
```

and I need to find all the moments where users have been in the same area( within 500 meters ).

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Use postgresql with postgis. postgis is a spatial database extender

Comment: Can you please be more specific about how close in time you consider a moment to be?

Comment: Are you willing and able to share this dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, so we don't have to write insanely complex SQL queries full of transcendental functions, let's define a stored function `distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)` to get ourselves a distance between two pairs of points.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distance$$

CREATE FUNCTION distance(
        lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT,
        lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT
     ) RETURNS FLOAT
    NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Returns the distance in metres on the Earth
             between two known points of latitude and longitude'
BEGIN
    RETURN 111045 * DEGREES(ACOS(
              COS(RADIANS(lat1)) *
              COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
              COS(RADIANS(lon2) - RADIANS(lon1)) +
              SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2))
            ));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now we need to compare pairs of items in your table to find coincidences. Let's say we want one-minute resolution on the time comparison. This query will do the trick, but take a while.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.IdUser, b.IdUser, 
                 DATE_FORMAT (a.EventDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00) AS EventDateTime
   FROM table a
   JOIN table b
          ON a.IdUser < b.IdUser    /* compare different users */
         AND a.EventDateTime >= b.EventDateTime - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
         AND a.EventDateTime <= b.EventDateTime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
         AND distance(a.Latitude, a.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Longitude) <= 500.0
```

This will work, giving a list of pairs of users and the hours in which they were near one another. But it won't be very fast.

You'll to experiment with indexes. Probably an index on `(EventDateTime, IdUser)` will help. You probably should experiment with this query by adding a time restriction like this...

```
   WHERE a.EventDateTime >= CURDATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
     AND a.EventDateTime <  CURDATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

so you don't take hours to run the query.

Now, let's try to do an optimization pass over the self-join, in an attempt to cut down the use of the `distance` function, and to use indexes better.   In order to do this, we need to know that there are ~11045m per degree of (north-south) latitude, so that 500m is 500/111045 degrees.

This query will generate pairs of observations that are within 500m north-to-south of each other,  then use a `WHERE` clause to further eliminate points that are still too far apart. That will reduce the use of the `distance` function.

```
 SELECT a.IdUser, b.IdUser, 
        DATE_FORMAT (a.EventDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00) AS EventDateTime
   FROM table a
   JOIN table b
             ON a.IdUser < b.IdUser    /* compare different users */
            AND a.EventDateTime >= b.EventDateTime - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
            AND a.EventDateTime <= b.EventDateTime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
            AND a.Latitude >= b.Latitude - (500.0/111045.0)
            AND a.Latitude <= b.Latitude + (500.0/111045.0)
  WHERE distance(a.Latitude, a.Longitude, b.Latitude, b.Longitude) <= 500.0
```

It is worth trying a compound covering index on `(IdUser, EventDateTime, Latitude, Longitude)` to try to optimize this query.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and complete response, but in this table i have over 2 milions rows and still it's taking a lot of time for this query to complete.  Even with the multicolumn index set on IdUser, EventDateTime, Lat and Long